# OS X Automator script : attach files to an email

Tags: macos, file, email, automator

I'm currently creating an Automator Workflow to attach several files in the Finder to an email

It seems to work for one file selected, but when I select several, only the first one in the list is added to the email. Yet, Automator detects the several files, but fails when sending it to Mail.app as seen in this screenshot :

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPHRB.png)

Any idea where it can be blocked ?

Many thanks!

Comment: Da codez, plz! You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply, but with Automator, there isn't any code :/

Comment: Well,as far as I know, Automator only hides the code. And if it isn't about code, it is off topic here and should rather be asked on http://www.superuser.com Please ***do not double-post***. If you agree, delete your question here and post there. ***Or*** wait for migration (I am voting to migrate it there, anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer, I have to run an applescript with the following code :

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Finder" to set myList to selection as alias list
    tell application "Mail"
        tell (item 1 of input) --
            repeat with i in myList
                make new attachment with properties {file name:i} at after the last paragraph of content
            end repeat
        end tell
    end tell
    return input
end run
```